# My program compiles and when ran, it doesn't give me the input i put in

Tags: c, arrays

The purpose of my program thus far is to create 4 arrays. 1 'char' array which will take in 10 different string values with each element having a maximum of 25 characters. And 3 other array's that will take in 10 integer values and store them into my array. I compile and run my program, and cycle through my for loops and once completed, I get some weird integer values in the place of my teamName array, and for the 'teamWins' 'teamLosses' and 'teamTies' arrays, it gives me the first value I input for ALL elements in those arrays. I really want to understand how arrays work but I am having trouble declaring them, and using them with input, and output. **Can anyone see and explain how I can take in 10 strings with values of 25 characters in each element, and take in 10 integers in the other 3 arrays with elements of 10?** I will attach my source code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NUM_TEAM 10

void displayWelcome(void);

int main(void)
{

char * teamName[NUM_TEAM + 1][30] = { "" };

int teamWins[NUM_TEAM] = {0};
int teamLosses[NUM_TEAM] = {0};
int teamTies[NUM_TEAM] = {0};
int i, bestPercent, worstPercent;

displayWelcome();

//Team Name
for (i = 0; i < NUM_TEAM; i++)
{
    //Prompt and enter team name
    printf("Enter %i's team name: ", i + 1);
    fgets (teamName[NUM_TEAM], sizeof teamName[NUM_TEAM], stdin);
    //Data validation
}

//Team wins
for (i = 0; i < NUM_TEAM; i++)
{
    printf("Enter wins for team number %i : ", i + 1);
    scanf("%i", &teamWins[ i ]);
    /*Data validation
    while ( 1 != scanf("%i", & teamWins) || teamWins <= 0)
    {
      fflush(stdin);
      printf("Enter a numerical value greater than zero: ");
    }*/
}
//Team losses
for (i = 0; i < NUM_TEAM; i++)
{
    printf("Enter losses for team number %i : ", i + 1);
    scanf("%i", &teamLosses[ i ]);
    /*Data validation
    while ( 1 != scanf("%i", & teamLosses) || teamLosses <= 0)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Enter a numerical value greater than zero: ");
    }*/
}
//Team ties
for (i = 0; i < NUM_TEAM; i++)
{
    printf("Enter ties for team number %i : ", i + 1);
    scanf("%i", &teamTies[ i ]);
    /*Data validation
    while ( 1 != scanf("%i", & teamTies) || teamTies <= 0)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Enter a numerical value greater than zero: ");
    }*/
}
//Display Data
for (i = 0; i < NUM_TEAM; i++)/* output each word read */
{
    printf("%s", teamName);
    printf("wins losses ties\n");
    printf("%i %i %i\n", teamName[i], teamWins[i], teamLosses[i], teamTies[i]);
}

return 0;
}

void displayWelcome(void)
{
    printf("Welcome to my Football Stats\n\n");
}
```

Comment: You print `teamName` instead of `temName[i]` and in the last `printf` the format string doesn't match the parameters. Doesn't your compiler warn  you about that?

Comment: If using `gcc` add `-Wall -Wextra` to your compile string. On windows (`cl.exe` -- VS), add `/Wall`. Do not accept code until it compiles without warning. (you may use `/W4` on windows, `/Wall` will trigger some non-code warnings that you cannot eliminate without specific `/wdXXX` disabling options.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got four issues:

1. Declaring `teamName` as `char * teamName[NUM_TEAM + 1][30] = { "" };` is incorrect; if you want an array of strings, it's sufficient to declare `char teamName[NUM_TEAM + 1][30] = { "" };` (you want a 2D array of `chars`, not `char *`s).
2. In `fgets (teamName[NUM_TEAM], sizeof teamName[NUM_TEAM], stdin);`, you're writing each team name to the same unused element. Instead, use `fgets (teamName[i], sizeof teamName[NUM_TEAM], stdin);` to write to the proper team during each iteration.
3. Printing using `printf("%s", teamName);` is incorrect; you want to print each team name rather than attempt to print the address of the `teamName` array: `printf("%s", teamName[i]);`
4. You have an extra argument in `printf("%i %i %i\n", teamName[i], teamWins[i], teamLosses[i], teamTies[i]);`; since you've already printed `teamName[i]` in Point 3, you should remove it in this `printf()` call: `printf("%i %i %i\n", teamWins[i], teamLosses[i], teamTies[i]);`

Comment: For 2. -- better yet, declare a constant for `30` and use that instead `:)`